# Jquery: Adding a new div with functions

Tags: jquery, html

this is my first post, so be gentle. :)

I have a link on my page.

I want to create a new div when clicking on the link.

The new div should contain the same link used to create this div, 
so that I can continue to create new divs containing the same link.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(searchCriteria);
    $(document).ready(loadSearchCriteria);

    function searchCriteria() {
        $(".test").load("searchCriteria.html");
    }

    function loadSearchCriteria() {
        $(".test1234").click(function () {
            $(".test1234").load("searchCriteria.html");
            function loadNewClick() {
                var $newClick = $('<div class="test1234"></div>');
                    $(".content").append($newClick);
            }
        });
    };

</script>
```

I'm using jquery-1.4.2.min.js

I'm new to jquery, so any tips would be appretiated.
Thx :)

Comment: You do not need two `$(document).ready()`s. You usually just have one doc ready block with the code you want to execute on dom ready inside.

Comment: @boz True, but in this case it won't hurt anything, and I don't think it makes the code less clear either.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call loadNewClickwhen your `$(".test").load("searchCriteria.html");` completes

```
$(".test").load("searchCriteria.html", function(){
    alert('completed');
    //EDIT:: this is your load new click function
    var $newClick = $('<div class="test1234"></div>');
    $(".content").append($newClick);
});
```

Comment: Thx for the respond. Yeah I have just created a function loadNewClick which I dont call afterwards, but I don't where you call the function loadNewClick? Sry I'm a webdesigner, so programming is somewhat new to me, though I've read some stuff about it.

Comment: @unebune You'll need to do this *in addition* to fixing the code so the new div gets the click event. I'd recommend getting everything else working using something simple like `.text()` before working with `.load()`, then come back to the load timing issue when that works. Basically, `load()` needs to send a request to the server, so all the other code carries on while that request is going on. You want your code to happen *when the request is finished*, so you need to tell 'load' to fire a callback function (as Philippe does here) that contains the code to run when `.load()` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    //document ready
    $(".test").load("searchCriteria.html");
    var $newClick = $('<div class="test1234">Sample div</div>');
    $(".content").append($newClick);
    $($newClick).live("click", function() {
        $(this).load("searchCriteria.html");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thx, but it didn't work.. Now only a static link shows and nohting else :/ <script>(your code)</script>

Comment: Using `live()` is fine for jQuery versions before 1.7 - in jQuery 1.7 and up, `live()` is deprecated to be [replaced with `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, this adapted code doesn't create new divs on click (but I guess that's fine, telling the OP about `live()` is the important bit)

Comment: @unebune: Does the `searchCriteria.html` page exists on your server??

Comment: sry I forgot to mention that i'm using 1.4.2.min.js.. rookie mistake.. So of course I should download latest version?

Comment: yes. searchCriteria.html exists and loads just fine into my main HTML page with the document.ready .load function.

Comment: Try putting an alert inside the click event and see if its working? And also see the console log, if there's any error!!

Comment: so running on 1.8.2.min.js, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So you want each of these newly appended .test1234 elements to have the same click event? You could use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to *delegate* the click event to the class. This effectively binds it to anything that gets that class, new or old (`.on()` replaces `.live()` in recent versions of jQuery).

---

But delegated events have (modest) overheads, and that might be excessive for something simple like this. When you create the new element, you can bind the function that created it to it. Binding events to newly created elements like this is a handy ["lesser known" jQuery trick](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/).

Here's **the important bit**: bind the function that creates the new div to the newly created div, like this (the click on a new line for readability):

```
 function somefunction() {
   var $newClick = $('<div class="test1234"></div>')
     .click( somefunction );
   $(".content").append($newClick);
 }
```

(you could also use `.click(function() { some code })`, or write it as `$('<div/>').addClass('test1234').click( somefunction );`, or whatever, it's very flexible)

I tested it this time :) and here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jP69z/) demonstrating the **full code** (using `.text()` instead of `.load()`.

I think the problem you mentioned in your comment is a different problem with the way your code is structured - have a look at the changes and comments in the jsfiddle code and think about what is happening when.

Change things, break it and reload it until it makes sense :).

---

---

Friendly tip from one javascript-coding designer to another - the hardest thing about learning real programming is getting your head around the *timing* and moving parts (what each thing is at each point). Remember that in jQuery things like `.click()` *bind* the event (`click()` is just a shortcut for `bind('click')`). I found it helpful when I was learning to use `.bind('click)` instead of `.click()` (and `bind('mouseover')` etc etc) so that when I read back over code, it was always intuitive to see exactly what was happening to what and when.

Also, use `console.log()` a lot. Log everything and watch what comes out as what at what pointn. And, think of your text editor/jsfiddle/firebug etc as an infinitely big sketchbook that *tells you* when something won't work: that's an awesome thing, try everything, and make lots of mistakes! It's the best way to learn.

Comment: wow thx... It seems to be a bit more advanced, can't quite get the view of it.. The result doesn't seem to do anything else but the original code: The click function works fine when first clicked, but it doesn't show up in a new div :/

Comment: You're right - $newClick isn't the new element added to the page. There's a fix to that, will be back...

Comment: @unebune - I found time to update it with refined code and a jsfiddle that demonstrates it in context.

Comment: Another friendly tip - you'll see in the jsfiddle that loaded elements still create new elements when clicked on. You might not want that... look into `.unbind('click')`

Comment: Thx dude... Very impressive, I will look into it later today when I get some spare time ;)